# In Spring Webflux how to go from an `OutputStream` to a `Flux<DataBuffer>`?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm building a tarball dynamically, and would like to stream it back directly, which should be 100% possible with a .tar.gz.

The below code is the closest thing I could get to a dataBuffer, through lots of googling. Basically, I need something that implements an `OutputStream` and provides, or publishes, to a `Flux<DataBuffer>` so that I can return that from my method, and have streaming output, instead of buffering the entire tarball in ram (which I'm pretty sure is what is happening here). I'm using apache Compress-commons, which has a wonderful API, but it's all OutputStream based.

I suppose another way to do it would be to directly write to the response, but I don't think that would be properly reactive? Not sure how to get an `OutputStream` out of some sort of Response object either.

This is kotlin btw, on Spring Boot 2.0

```
@GetMapping("/cookbook.tar.gz", "/cookbook")
fun getCookbook(): Mono<DefaultDataBuffer> {
    log.info("Creating tarball of cookbooks: ${soloConfig.cookbookPaths}")

    val transformation = Mono.just(soloConfig.cookbookPaths.stream()
            .toList()
            .flatMap {
                Files.walk(Paths.get(it)).map(Path::toFile).toList()
            })
            .map { files ->

                //Will make one giant databuffer... but oh well? TODO: maybe use some kind of chunking.
                val buffer = DefaultDataBufferFactory().allocateBuffer()
                val outputBufferStream = buffer.asOutputStream()


                //Transform my list of stuff into an archiveOutputStream
                TarArchiveOutputStream(GzipCompressorOutputStream(outputBufferStream)).use { taos ->
                    taos.setLongFileMode(TarArchiveOutputStream.LONGFILE_GNU)

                    log.info("files to compress: ${files}")

                    for (file in files) {
                        if (file.isFile) {
                            val entry = "cookbooks/" + file.name
                            log.info("Adding ${entry} to tarball")
                            taos.putArchiveEntry(TarArchiveEntry(file, entry))
                            FileInputStream(file).use { fis ->
                                fis.copyTo(taos) //Copy that stuff!
                            }
                            taos.closeArchiveEntry()
                        }
                    }
                }
                buffer
            }

    return transformation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I puzzled through this, and have an effective solution. You implement an `OutputStream` and take those bytes and publish them into a stream. Be sure to override close, and send an onComplete. Works great!

```
@RestController
class SoloController(
        val soloConfig: SoloConfig
) {
    val log = KotlinLogging.logger { }

    @GetMapping("/cookbooks.tar.gz", "/cookbooks")
    fun streamCookbook(serverHttpResponse: ServerHttpResponse): Flux<DataBuffer> {
        log.info("Creating tarball of cookbooks: ${soloConfig.cookbookPaths}")

        val publishingOutputStream = PublishingOutputStream(serverHttpResponse.bufferFactory())

        //Needs to set up cookbook path as a parent directory, and then do `cookbooks/$cookbook_path/<all files>` for each cookbook path given
        Flux.just(soloConfig.cookbookPaths.stream().toList())
                .doOnNext { paths ->
                    //Transform my list of stuff into an archiveOutputStream
                    TarArchiveOutputStream(GzipCompressorOutputStream(publishingOutputStream)).use { taos ->
                        taos.setLongFileMode(TarArchiveOutputStream.LONGFILE_GNU)

                        paths.forEach { cookbookDir ->
                            if (Paths.get(cookbookDir).toFile().isDirectory) {

                                val cookbookDirFile = Paths.get(cookbookDir).toFile()
                                val directoryName = cookbookDirFile.name
                                val entryStart = "cookbooks/${directoryName}"

                                val files = Files.walk(cookbookDirFile.toPath()).map(Path::toFile).toList()

                                log.info("${files.size} files to compress")

                                for (file in files) {
                                    if (file.isFile) {
                                        val relativePath = file.toRelativeString(cookbookDirFile)
                                        val entry = "$entryStart/$relativePath"
                                        taos.putArchiveEntry(TarArchiveEntry(file, entry))
                                        FileInputStream(file).use { fis ->
                                            fis.copyTo(taos) //Copy that stuff!
                                        }
                                        taos.closeArchiveEntry()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                .doOnComplete {
                    publishingOutputStream.close()
                }
                .subscribe()

        return publishingOutputStream.publisher
    }

    class PublishingOutputStream(bufferFactory: DataBufferFactory) : OutputStream() {

        val publisher: UnicastProcessor<DataBuffer> = UnicastProcessor.create(Queues.unbounded<DataBuffer>().get())
        private val bufferPublisher: UnicastProcessor<Byte> = UnicastProcessor.create(Queues.unbounded<Byte>().get())

        init {
            bufferPublisher
                    .bufferTimeout(4096, Duration.ofMillis(100))
                    .doOnNext { intList ->
                        val buffer = bufferFactory.allocateBuffer(intList.size)
                        buffer.write(intList.toByteArray())
                        publisher.onNext(buffer)
                    }
                    .doOnComplete {
                        publisher.onComplete()
                    }
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newSingle("publisherThread"))
                    .subscribe()
        }

        override fun write(b: Int) {
            bufferPublisher.onNext(b.toByte())
        }

        override fun close() {
            bufferPublisher.onComplete() //which should trigger the clean up of the whole thing
        }
    }
}
```